# Is logical replication using pglogical possible with timescaleDB?

Tags: postgresql, replication, timescaledb, pglogical

I set up a fully functional logical replication of multiple masters to one slave.

As soon as I convert any of the replicated tables to timescaleDB's [hypertable](http://www.timescale.com/how-it-works), the replication stops working - only the structure is replicated, but no data.

Is it possible to use timescaleDB together with pglogical? Would it be possible to use PostgreSQL 10 and its in-built logical replication abilities?

My guess is, that logical replication doesn't make sense in the context of tables consisting of virtual chunks.

Comment: chunks in TimescaleDB db are partitions of the main hypertable interconnected with inheritance. Therefore read this - https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/pg-phriday-pglogical-postgres-10-partitions/ - it should help you

Comment: I set _pglogical.conflict_resolution = error_ and _pglogical.use_spi = true_ like suggested; it still doesn't work and just replicates structures. The proposed _pglogical.conflict_resolution = false_ is wrong and leads to errors, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

No.

> To our knowledge, PG10's logical replication will not work with
>   hypertables, because it actually doesn't replicate DDL commands, and
>   instead just does a pub/sub on the data.
>   - Mike Freedman, CTO TimescaleDB (04.04.2019)

More info: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/1138#issuecomment-479674594